# Debug assert "Invalid format directive" for std::put_time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I'm learning to use C++11 chrono, and am trying to output the time.
[Other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347371/stdput-time-formats) show some code samples, e.g.

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - std::chrono::hours(24));
std::cout  << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_c), "%F %T") << '\n';
```

When I run this on VS2012 in debug, I get a debug assert claiming I've used an "Invalid format directive".

The same happens if I use `std::strftime`. I presume the `%F` and `%T` are not supported by Microsoft?

Comment: Did you check [what MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: I have just read that. Thanks Roger. This format seems to work "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S". It's hard going reading about C++11 and trying to use VS2012.

Comment: Yes - VS2012 only partially supports C++11 so confusion is inevitable :-( [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) for details of what it does/doesn't do.

Comment: VS2015 does have these

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is purely because %F and %T are not supported by Microsoft.