# get a set time before and after an iso 8601 timestamp c++

Tags: c++, c++11

given a standard ISO 8601 timestamp, is there an easy way to get a time stamp from 20 minutes before and another time stamp of 20 minutes after the original timestamp?

For example given

```
 2010-01-25 18:02:00
```

I would want one or two functions to return,
`2010-01-25 17:48:00` and  `2010-01-25 18:22:00`

The solution I gave up with is rather cumbersome, I use `s.substr(14,2)` to get the minutes and `s.substr(12,2)` to get the hours, convert the hour and minute strings to int and subtract or add the minute value with a condition if it goes above 60 or below 0. Is there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: What is the time 20 minutes after 2012-12-31 23:59:00 ? I guess there is no easy way.

Comment: @BoPersson yeah true i didn't even think of that case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could:

1. Convert the string into a `struct tm` [using `std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).
2. Modify the `struct tm` (no need to consider the ranges).
3. Normalize the `struct tm` [using `mktime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime).
4. Print the `struct tm` [using `std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time)

---

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string increase_minutes(const std::string& input, int delta) {
    struct tm tm;
    constexpr auto format = "%Y-%m-%d %T";

    std::istringstream iss (input);
    iss >> std::get_time(&tm, format);
    tm.tm_min += delta;
    mktime(&tm);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(&tm, format);
    return oss.str();
}


int main() {
    auto s = "2012-12-31 23:59:00";
    std::cout << increase_minutes(s, 20) << std::endl;
    std::cout << increase_minutes(s, -20) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that `std::get_time` and `std::put_time` are absent in g++/libstdc++. You may need to parse the string using the C functions `sscanf` or `strptime`, and print the string using `strftime`. See also [C++ date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346260/c-date-and-time).

---

**Edit:** If we want to change by a generic `std::chrono::duration`, it is better we manipulate on a `std::chrono::time_point` directly. We could create a time_point from a `struct tm` with a two-step conversion: time_point ↔ time_t ↔ struct tm, as illustrated below:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>

template <typename R, typename P>
std::string increase_iso_time(const std::string& input, 
                              const std::chrono::duration<R, P>& duration) {
    struct tm tm;
    constexpr auto format = "%Y-%m-%d %T";

    std::istringstream iss (input);
    iss >> std::get_time(&tm, format);
    auto time = mktime(&tm);
    auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time);

    tp += duration;

    time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    tm = *localtime(&time);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(&tm, format);
    return oss.str();
}

int main() {
    auto s = "2012-12-31 23:59:00";
    std::cout << increase_iso_time(s, std::chrono::minutes(20)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << increase_iso_time(s, - std::chrono::hours(4)
                                      - std::chrono::minutes(20)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 Those C++11 time I/O manipulators sure are handy!  One possible improvement:  You could increase the type safety of `increase_minutes` by changing the type of `delta` to `std::chrono::minutes`.  It does make the user code more verbose, but also makes it non-ambiguous as to what `20` actually means.  On the other hand, the name of your function also strives to disambiguate the `20`.  So this isn't a huge deal, just another design decision.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: If we want to accept a `std::duration`, it would be better to convert that `tm` into a `time_point`. Updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I was thinking of doing it.  But your original use of `mktime` to normalize the `tm` is elegant too.  I'm sure both are overkill for a homework exercise. :-)  If you really want to beat this horse to death, you could template on `Rep` and `Period`, making the parameter `std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>`.  That makes `increase_iso_time` not "overly generic" in the `duration` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Look up `mktime()` from the C or C++ standards.  You'll need something like `strptime()` to convert the ISO 8601 time into a `struct tm` (or you can use `sscanf()`, or ...).  Then make two copies of your structure, adjust the `tm_min` by +20 in one and -20 in the other, call `mktime()`, and then `strftime()`.

This will work in C and C++98, C++2003 as well as C++2011.  If you want it only to work with C++2011, then you need to go to `std::chrono`.

#### Sample code

This code is for C++ because of the headers, but could be converted to C by changing to `<time.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.  Yes, it probably doesn't count as 'good' C++; it certainly leaves you with some interface decisions.  But it does get the job done.  (For pure C++, you can remove the references to `struct`.)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

static void delta_t(const char *otime, int delta)
{
    struct tm tm1;
    int n;
    if ((n = sscanf(otime, "%4d-%2d-%2d %2d:%2d:%2d", &tm1.tm_year, &tm1.tm_mon, &tm1.tm_mday,
                    &tm1.tm_hour, &tm1.tm_min, &tm1.tm_sec)) != 6)
    {
        printf("%s: failed %d\n", otime, n);
        return;
    }
    printf("%.4d-%.2d-%.2d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n", tm1.tm_year, tm1.tm_mon, tm1.tm_mday,
            tm1.tm_hour, tm1.tm_min, tm1.tm_sec);

    tm1.tm_isdst = -1;
    tm1.tm_year -= 1900;
    tm1.tm_mon--;
    struct tm tm2 = tm1;
    tm2.tm_min += delta;
    struct tm tm3 = tm1;
    tm3.tm_min -= delta;
    mktime(&tm2);
    mktime(&tm3);
    char dt1[20];
    char dt2[20];
    char dt3[20];
    strftime(dt1, sizeof(dt1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm1);
    strftime(dt2, sizeof(dt2), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm2);
    strftime(dt3, sizeof(dt3), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm3);

    printf("Input: %s\n", otime);
    printf("Date1: %s\n", dt1);
    printf("Date2: %s\n", dt2);
    printf("Date3: %s\n", dt3);
}

int main(void)
{
    delta_t("2010-01-25 18:02:00", 20);
    delta_t("2012-12-31 23:59:00", 20);
    return(0);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
2010-01-25 18:02:00
Input: 2010-01-25 18:02:00
Date1: 2010-01-25 18:02:00
Date2: 2010-01-25 18:22:00
Date3: 2010-01-25 17:42:00
2012-12-31 23:59:00
Input: 2012-12-31 23:59:00
Date1: 2012-12-31 23:59:00
Date2: 2013-01-01 00:19:00
Date3: 2012-12-31 23:39:00
```