# Outputting Date and Time in C++ using std::chrono

Tags: c++, date, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I have been upgrading some old code and have been trying to update to c++11 where possible. The following code is how I used to display the time and date in my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

const std::string return_current_time_and_date() const
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);
    return buf;
}
```

I would like to output the current time and date in a similar format using std::chrono(or similar) but am unsure how to go about doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please lookup if there's already such a question asked and if not then ask.

Comment: *Possible Duplicate:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346260/c-date-and-time

Comment: You're not going to get much better with C++11. chrono is more about timing (how long did something take) than time-of-day type stuff.  You might check out Boost Date Time, though. It has more robust date&time functionality.

Comment: Get date&time using chrono and output? See the [first example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point).

Comment: @DyP That looks promising but I need to return a string from the function and not sure how to go about doing so with std::put_time

Comment: Lookout on std::localtime or std::gmtime those functions aren't thread safe!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70684900/1201614

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The `<chrono>` library only deals with time and not dates, except for the `system_clock` which has the ability to convert its timepoints to `time_t`. So using `<chrono>` for dates will not improve things much. Hopefully we get something like [`chrono::date`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) in the not too distant future.

That said, you can use `<chrono>` in the following way:

```
#include <chrono>  // chrono::system_clock
#include <ctime>   // localtime
#include <sstream> // stringstream
#include <iomanip> // put_time
#include <string>  // string

std::string return_current_time_and_date()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&in_time_t), "%Y-%m-%d %X");
    return ss.str();
}
```

Note that `std::localtime` may cause data races. `localtime_r` or similar functions may be available on your platforms.

Update:

Using a new version of Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) you can write:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string return_current_time_and_date() {
  auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto today = date::floor<days>(now);

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << today << ' ' << date::make_time(now - today) << " UTC";
  return ss.str();
}
```

This will print out something like "2015-07-24 05:15:34.043473124 UTC".

---

On an unrelated note, returning `const` objects has become undesirable with C++11; const return values cannot be moved from. I also removed the trailing const because trailing const is only valid for member functions and this function has no need to be a member.

Comment: Beware that some old compilers might not recognize `std::put_time`. Once I tried to compile my code that had `std::put_time` on CentOS 7 using g++, it failed. Status of `std::put_time` support in GCC http://stackoverflow.com/q/14136833/4694036

Comment: is there C++ function similar to std::put_time but to return string?

Comment: @Nick No. The C function `strftime` will let you fill a buffer with a C string. The obsoleted function `asctime` will return a C string in a fixed time format.

Comment: thanks, well i guess you can do put_time with string stream

Comment: Refering to the update using Hinnant's date library: Under MSVC2015 I needed to put a `using namespace date;` right before using the `<<` operator for the `days` type in order to compile.

Comment: @yau you could use `date::days` instead

Comment: if you don't use `using namespace date;` the `<< today` will not work.

Answer (score 50):

Here's a C++20 solution:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <format>

std::string get_current_time_and_date()
{
    auto const time = std::chrono::current_zone()
        ->to_local(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    return std::format("{:%Y-%m-%d %X}", time);
}
```

`std::chrono::time_zone::to_local` converts a system clock time point (`std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, TDuration>`) to a local time point (`std::chrono::local_time<TDuration>`). This local time point can then be formatted using `std::format` with formatting options similar to `strftime`.

Currently, only MSVC has implemented `std::format`. The calendar and timezone additions to chrono are currently "partially" implemented by Clang and GCC, but check here for the updated status: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support. For more information about the `chrono` library, read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono.

Comment: Does clang or gcc implement the timezone part of the `<chrono>` library? Even if we drop `std::format` from the example, can the above code be tested in Godbolt or Wandbox?

Comment: The easiest way to find out would be by... testing it in Godbolt or Wandbox.

Comment: Actually, I guess I could add that information to the answer to make it more complete. Thanks

Comment: Sadly, doesn’t work with gcc 11 or clang 13 or, really, any compiler I tried on Compiler Explorer.

Comment: calling `to_local()` in MSVC produces a huge memory leak

Comment: "<format>" file not found, "current_zone" is not a member of std::chrono...  What's the heck with C++20 and compilers? (we are in 2023 now).

Comment: This works with "gcc (trunk)", "clang (trunk)" and the latest MSVC release on compiler explorer now, so we should expect all three compilers to support these features pretty soon I think :)

Answer (score 18):

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

std::string getTimeStr(){
    std::time_t now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    std::string s(30, '\0');
    std::strftime(&s[0], s.size(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", std::localtime(&now));
    return s;
}
int main(){

    std::cout<<getTimeStr()<<std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Output as below:

[image]

Comment: NOT THREAD SAFE see [Data races](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/)

Comment: Downvote: The current answer returns a 30-character long string with lots of null characters on the end. If you attempt to concatenate something to it, it will not work.  I did suggest an edit to make it work, but it was rejected by Django programmers....

Answer (score 8):

For getting also milliseconds, I use chrono and C function localtime_r which is thread-safe (in opposition to std::localtime).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>


int main() {
  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::time_t currentTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
  std::chrono::milliseconds now2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
  struct tm currentLocalTime;
  localtime_r(&currentTime, &currentLocalTime);
  char timeBuffer[80];
  std::size_t charCount { std::strftime( timeBuffer, 80,
                                         "%D %T",
                                          &currentLocalTime)
                         };

  if (charCount == 0) return -1;

  std::cout << timeBuffer << "." << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << now2.count() % 1000 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For format: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

Comment: Since you're already importing iomanip, you can skip creating your own buffer by using std::put_time instead of std::strftime.

Comment: You may appear off by half a second, since `to_time_t` may truncate, but might also round.

Comment: Don't you have to apply a clock type template argument?
``std::chrono::system_clock::time_point<system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();``

Answer (score 6):

The fmt library has the ability to format `tm` structures: it has the same spec as strftime.

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

std::string current_datetime(void)
{
  std::time_t tt = std::time(nullptr);
  std::tm *tm = std::localtime(&tt);
  return fmt::format("{:%Y%m%d}", *tm);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

bames53 solutions are good, but do not compile on my VS2017. The solution with ctime does not compile because localtime is very deprecated. The one with date.h does not compile with the current date.h I just took off github even though the documentation says they should, because today cannot be streamed as is. I omitted the includes but here is code that works:

```
void TimeTest()
{
    auto n = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto in_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(n);
    std::tm buf;
    localtime_s(&buf, &in_time_t);
    std::cout << std::put_time(&buf, "%Y-%m-%d %X") << std::endl;

}

// I just added date.h from this link's guthub to the project.
// https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html
void TimeTest1() {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto today =  floor<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::cout << date::year_month_day{ today } << ' ' << date::make_time(now - today) << std::endl;
}

// output is 
// 2018-04-08 21:19:49
// 2018-04-08 18:19:49.8408289
```

Feel free to fix bames53 solution and delete mine. My text just won't fit in a comment. I'm sure it can save many people from grief.

Comment: If you add `using date::operator<<;` you can stream `today` without converting it to `year_month_day`.

Comment: Howard, thank you so much for writing and sharing this library. To the point, I'd rather never use using as I've suffered bugs and ambiguity from namespace collisions enough in my days. Also, if we are being precise I'd like to note that the first example outputs local time while the second is universal time.

Comment: Glad I can help.  `usings` at function scope are a good compromise since conflicts are easier to control when they occur.  I realize this isn't perfect, but it is the best that can be done for stream insertion operators for std::types, written by 3rd party libraries.  But just last month I convinced the C++ committee to place this streaming operator in `namespace std::chrono` for C++20 so that it will be found by ADL.  Then it will no longer require a `using`.

Comment: Good observation about the output being UTC.  Also available is a higher-level library that provides operations with local time.  That can be with your computer's current local time zone, or with a specifically designated time zone (e.g. "America/New_York").  Here is the [documentation for the time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

Comment: @HowardHinnant: we're still missing your `operator<<` in the standard. Can you please give a status?

Comment: It is in C++20:  http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system.nonmembers#4  Vendors are at work implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

Although correct answers were already given, I decided to implement one more solution that outputs also fractional part of second.

You may notice in my code that sometimes I subtract one second from `time_t` value, `- std::chrono::seconds(1)`, it is because according to [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t) `to_time_t()` may round value instead of truncating (according to doc "If std::time_t has lower precision, it is implementation-defined whether the value is rounded or truncated"), hence I have to subtract 1 second to make it truncated time.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/q6rcaW5a6)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string FormatTime(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    auto t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    auto tp2 = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(t);
    if (tp2 > tp)
        t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp - std::chrono::seconds(1));
    ss  << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%Y-%m-%d %T")
        << "." << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3)
        << (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
           tp.time_since_epoch()).count() % 1000);
    return ss.str();
}

std::string CurrentTimeStr() {
    return FormatTime(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << CurrentTimeStr() << std::endl;
}
```

Example Output:

```
2021-12-02 04:10:51.876
```

---

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223096/outputting-date-and-time-in-c-using-stdchrono/70194115?noredirect=1#comment127229345_70194115) by @AndyK, starting from C++20 you can use [std::chrono::current_zone()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/current_zone) and its method [to_local()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_zone/to_local), they return [std::chrono::local_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/local_t) which is directly convertible to your desired string format by outputting to `std::ostringstream` or through [std::format()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). Whole function becomes very short:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::string CurrentTimeStr() {
    return (std::ostringstream{} << std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(
        std::chrono::system_clock::now())).str().substr(0, 23);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << CurrentTimeStr() << std::endl;
}
```

But right now not all compilers support this `current_zone()` function, online GodBolt servers failed to compile it on trunk CLang and GCC, but MSVC compiles it well. Although my local laptop installation of CLang compiled it too.

Comment: This is equivalent and a bit briefer: 
std::string CurrentTimeStr()
{   using namespace std::chrono;
    auto tp = system_clock::now();
    auto us = duration_cast<microseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count() % 1000000;
    return std::format("{:%Y-%m-%d %T}.{:06}", current_zone()->to_local(tp), us);
}

Comment: The format should be {:%Y-%m-%d %X}. My code is of course for microseconds, rather than milliseconds - cast to milliseconds and use {:03} to format for milliseconds.

Comment: @AndyK Even if your code works correctly, still I couldn't test it because `std::format` and `std::chrono::current_zone()` are both not yet implemented in most recent versions of CLang and GCC, [see online link](https://godbolt.org/z/vh8cv4sfG) you may see that CLang/GCC can't compile it.

Comment: @AndyK On online latest MSVC compiler it comiles, [see online here](https://godbolt.org/z/Yf7fT9a8P), but throws an exception at runtime `The specified module could not be found.`. So also needs probably some tweaking of MSVC compiler.

Comment: @AndyK On my local home laptop your MSVC version works correctly! So great, you have a nice solution! You may post it as a separate answer to this question, not only in comments to my answer. BTW, if I use `%T` instead of `%X` as so `{:%Y-%m-%d %T}` then it already outputs 7 digits after dot, no need for extra `.{:06}`, you may just resize final string to smaller one if you need less digits.

Comment: @AndyK Thanks for suggestion! Updated my answer and included your `current_zone()` function usage in my second code snippet. Also made code even much more shorter than you suggested.

Comment: I didn't know about that .{06} tweak.  Thanks for that.  I still find chrono hard to get to grips with! I did this on my local Visual Studio install using the latest C++ language spec - should have mentioned that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve the answer from @bames53 by using Boost lexical_cast instead of string stream manipulations.

Here is what I do:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <ctime>

std::string return_current_time_and_date() {
    auto current_time = std::time(0);
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(std::put_time(std::gmtime(& current_time), "%Y-%m-%d %X"));
}
```

Comment: also iomanip is needed https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Answer (score -1):

This is the best and the simplest way in my opinion to print the current time:

```
string setCurrentDate() {
        time_t currentTime{time(nullptr)};
        string date = ctime(&currentTime);
        return date;
    }
```

time() functions takes a pointer to time_t variable to store the current time in this variable(You can pass the nullptr also).

ctime() functions takes a pointer to time_t variable to convert it to a string representation(a human-readable ASCII string).

Note: The ctime() function appends a newline character ('\n') at the end of the string

if you print the returned date, it will be something like that:

```
Tue Aug 01 02:11:31 2023
```

Comment: While this would be a good answer for someone explicitly **not** wanting to use chrono, this answer is in the wrong place.