# C++11 get current date and time as string

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11

What is the state of the art way to get date and time as string in c++11?

I know about `std::put_time`, but the reference says I shall use it only in streams.

There is `std::chrono::system_clock` which provides `to_time_t` returning the time as `time_t` and lacking the date, doesn't it?

I could use a stringstream like bames53: [Outputting Date and Time in C++ using std::chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223096/outputting-date-and-time-in-c-using-stdchrono) but that seems to be a workaround.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime.

Comment: Personally I'd stay away from std::chrono but it's your call. abhishek ratore's answer is a very good one in that regard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source header-only datetime library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), you can get the current UTC time as a `std::string` in a single line of code:

```
std::string s = date::format("%F %T", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

I just ran this, and the string contains:

```
2017-03-30 17:05:13.400455
```

That's right, it even gives you the full precision.  If you don't like that format, all of the `strftime` formatting flags are available.  If you want your local time, there is a [timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) also available, though it is not header only.

```
std::string s = date::format("%F %T %Z", date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(),
                                         std::chrono::system_clock::now()));
```

Output:

```
2017-03-30 13:05:13.400455 EDT
```

### Update for C++20

This can now be done with the std::lib headers `<chrono>` and `<format>`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    std::string s1 = std::format("{:%F %T}", std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::string s2 = std::format("{:%F %T %Z}",
        std::chrono::zoned_time{std::chrono::current_zone(),
                                std::chrono::system_clock::now()});
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xhvef7fd8).

Comment: Yes, date.h is 100% thread safe.  It does not use the underlying thread-unsafe C API, nor does it rely on thread-unsafe practices such as setting environment variables.  The time zone library is also thread safe, including the initialization of the timezone library upon first use (which depends on C++11 thread safe function local statics).

Comment: The only part that relies on user-supplied synchronization is the rarely used feature of re-loading the timezone database after first use (which one might use after the application has been running for months).  And this characteristic is fully documented: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#database

Comment: Thank you for this great library Howard. I was able to replace 7 lines using the unsafe and clunky strftime() into 1 line! Please propose to the Standard Committee (if you haven't already).

Comment: Thanks @Ricky65!  You can find the current standardization process of this library near the bottom of the README here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: Thanks for the link. Hopefully it will make it into C++20. Marvelous! Thanks for proposing.

Comment: It uses the C API because std::chrono is heavily reliant on the C standard library in most implementations that matter. std::chrono is just a thin wrapper on top of the C standard library by the way.

Comment: The C API won't do sub-second precision. `std::chrono` will. The C API has two time zones: UTC and local. `std::chrono` has those two plus all the [IANA time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). The C API doesn't specify whether or not leap seconds are counted, and in practice never does (tracks [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). `std::chrono` will let you compute both in Unix Time and in true UTC with leap seconds. `std::chrono` makes it trivial to compute the 3rd Thu of May this year. Not so in the C API. Etc., etc.

Answer (score 9):

Simpler:

```
string CurrentDate()
{
    std::time_t now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    char buf[100] = {0};
    std::strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d", std::localtime(&now));
    return buf;
}
```

Adjust the format as appropriate for the time too.

Note that I suspect this will not work well for multithreaded code since `std::localtime()` returns a pointer to an internal struct.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, `std::time_t` indeed captures both date and time, since it generally represents seconds from January 1st, 1970.

There is no *great* support for handling dates in C++11. You still have to depend on boost if you don't wish to do it, mostly, manually. Here's how to do it manually.

You can use it—in a thread-safe way—together with any `std::chrono::*clock`, such as `std::system_clock`, like this:

```
std::string get_date_string(std::chrono::time_point t) {
  auto as_time_t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(t);
  struct tm tm;
  if (::gmtime_r(&as_time_t, &tm))
    if (std::strftime(some_buffer, sizeof(some_buffer), "%F", &tm))
      return std::string{some_buffer};
  throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get current date as string");
}
```

Somewhere else, you can issue:

```
get_date_string(std::system_clock::now());
```

The *relatively good* thing about this solution is that, at the API level, you're still using modern, portable C++ concepts such as `std::chrono::time_point`, and of course, `std::string`.

Comment: Nice. You might want to use `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` for the function argument. The buffer `some_buffer` is char array (e.g. `char some_buffer[64];`) that must be declared inside the function and must not be static (otherwise the whole thread safety is lost). You could reuse the `std::string` internal buffer for that (resize, then contract) and avoid copying.

Answer (score 4):

timestamp like this;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int main() {

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t start_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    char timedisplay[100];
    struct tm buf;
    errno_t err = localtime_s(&buf, &start_time);
    if (std::strftime(timedisplay, sizeof(timedisplay), "%H:%M:%S", &buf)) {
        std::cout << timedisplay << '\n';
    }
}
```

Date in a similar manner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code snippet given below as it will serve your purpose. Here use **time.h** header file for required **localtime()** function and then using the **strftime()** function with required parameters will give the output and it returns it as a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
std::string current_date();
std::string current_time();
int main(){
    std::cout<<"Current date => "<<current_date()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"Current time => "<<current_time()<<"\n";
}
std::string current_date(){
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[40];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    //format: day DD-MM-YYYY
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%A %d/%m/%Y", &tstruct);
    return buf;
}
std::string current_time(){
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[40];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    //format: HH:mm:ss
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", &tstruct);
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Since `std::string` is returned, temporal `std::string buf` is a better option. That would remove an extra overhead for constructing string from a char buffer. In provided example `return buf` == `std::string(buf)`, which invoke `memcpy` to copy 'buf' into newly created return sting. After all: `std::string buf; buf.resize(40); ...  strftime((char*)buf.data(), 40, "%A %d/%m/%Y", &tstruct);`