# boost log text_file_backend performance

Tags: performance, boost, rotation, backend, boost-log

I am using boost log and I choose the text_file_backend, but I got bad performance. No matter sync or async, the boost log has a low performance. About in 6 seconds, it wrote 30M data to log file. 
Follow is my code snippet, anyone can help me?

```
    typedef boost::log::sinks::asynchronous_sink<
      boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend> TextSink; 
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<LogSev> logger_;
    boost::shared_ptr<TextSink> report_sink_;

    // initialize report_sink
    boost::shared_ptr<sinks::text_file_backend> report_backend =
        boost::make_shared<sinks::text_file_backend>(
            keywords::file_name = target + "/" + file_name
                + ".report.log.%Y_%m_%d.%N",
            keywords::rotation_size = file_size, keywords::time_based_rotation =
                sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
            keywords::auto_flush = false);

    boost::shared_ptr<sinks::file::collector> report_collector = CreateCollector(
        target, max_use_size / 2, min_free_size);
    report_backend->set_file_collector(report_collector);
    report_backend->scan_for_files();

    // add sink: report_sink
    report_sink_ = boost::make_shared<TextSink>(report_backend);
    report_sink_->set_formatter(
        expr::format("[%1%]" + sep + "[%2%]" + sep + "[%3%]" + sep + "%4%")
            % expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>(
                "TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            % expr::attr<LogSev>("Severity")
            % expr::attr<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID")
            % expr::message);
    report_sink_->set_filter(expr::attr<LogSev>("Severity") >= report);
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(report_sink_);

    logging::add_common_attributes();

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger_, info) << "blabal...";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one performance issue about your implementation is about `Timestamp`. It needs a system-call to find Time. I encountered the same problem. So I turned to use [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library. It returns UTC time very fast. Also check first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963738/c11-get-current-date-and-time-as-string) question, However if you want Timestamp based on timezone, date library is slow. you should better define your timezone and add to UTC.

see the example:

```
#include "date.h"

#define MY_TIME std::chrono::hours(4) + std::chrono::minutes(30)

string timestamp = date::format("%F %T", std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 
                                MY_TIME);
```