# Convert 32 bit unix timestamp to std::string using std::chrono

Tags: c++, c, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I am trying to use `std::chrono` to make a `std::string` but running into issues.

Here is the C(-ish) code I want to mimick:

```
std::uint32_t time_date_stamp = 1484693089;
char date[100];
struct tm *t = gmtime(reinterpret_cast<const time_t*>(&time_date_stamp));
strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p", t);
```

My starting point is always this `std::uint32_t`, it is from a data format I do not control.

Sorry I do not have any C++ as a starting point, I do not even know how to make a `std::chrono::time_point` correctly.

Comment: I think you better  use `strftime` as usual way to stringify `std::chrono` is to convert to `time_t`

Comment: OP could also use [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time)

Comment: A very tight tangent: [Outputting Date and Time in C++ using std::chrono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223096/outputting-date-and-time-in-c-using-stdchrono) Also links to Howard Hinnant's... Eh... he just posted an answer, didn't he?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<chrono>` is not a library for formatting datetimes into strings. It is useful for converting different time representations (milliseconds to days, etc), adding timestamps together and such.

The only datetime formatting functions in the standard library are the ones inherited from the C standard library, including the `std::strftime` which you already used in the "C(-ish)" version. EDIT: As pointed out by jaggedSpire, C++11 introduced `std::put_time`. It provides a convenient way to stream formatted dates with the same API as used by the C functions.

Since `std::gmtime` (and `std::localtime` if you were to use that) take their argument as a unix timestamp, you don't need `<chrono>` to convert the time. It is already in the correct representation. Only the underlying type must be converted from `std::uint32_t` to `std::time_t`. That is not implemented portably in your C version.

A portable way to convert the timestamp, with `std::put_time` based formatting:

```
std::uint32_t time_date_stamp = 1484693089;
std::time_t temp = time_date_stamp;
std::tm* t = std::gmtime(&temp);
std::stringstream ss; // or if you're going to print, just input directly into the output stream
ss << std::put_time(t, "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p");
std::string output = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an easy way to do it without dropping down to C's `tm` using this portable [C++11/14 free, open-source, header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    std::uint32_t time_date_stamp = 1484693089;
    date::sys_seconds tp{std::chrono::seconds{time_date_stamp}};
    std::string s = date::format("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p", tp);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
2017-01-17 10:44:49 PM
```

This does not have the thread-safety issues associated with the ancient `gmtime` C function.

`date::sys_seconds` above is a `typedef` for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds>`.

Comment: I'm concerned that the header-only library `date.h` has 8000 lines and it includes about 22 other headers (standard c++ stuff, but man...)

Comment: When your vendor ships a complete C++20, `date.h` can be replaced by `<chrono>`, and `sys_seconds` will be in namespace `std::chrono` and `format` will be in namespace `std`.