# I'm trying to get current date and time in cpp but can't understand these lines

Tags: c++

Pls can anybody explain me these two lines

```
// Current date/time based on current system


time_t now = time(0);

// Convert now to tm struct for local timezone


tm* localtm = localtime(&now);
```

Comment: Did you check the man pages?

Answer (score 3):

That is a very old C-styled way of determining local date & time based on `time.h`. The documentation for that header file explains a lot, but to summarize, `time()` returns a system-time in seconds from *Epoch* (00:00 on 1-Jan-1970) when passed a *null pointer* (hence the zero), or time from another set `time_t` instance. The pointer here is essential because it drives different behaviors of the function based on the pointer value.

`localtime()` takes system-time information and converts it to a local-time based upon current system settings. I've never been sure why this took a pointer as an argument, but I assume it's just to maintain consistency with the API.

A better, more C++ way of getting local-time is to use the `std::chrono` library (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/?kw=chrono). You could get higher resolution local-time (instead of just accurate to the nearest second), without pointer-jockeying. For example, please refer to: [Outputting Date and Time in C++ using std::chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223096/outputting-date-and-time-in-c-using-stdchrono)