# Converting string with datetime value to one with date and time in C/C++ on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, datetime

I am developing a C++ application on Visual Studio in which I have a string that contains a datetime value and I must convert it into another string with the date and time in the format dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS

For example, if the string sDateTime has the value "1643873040", I must get another string sDateAndTime with the value "02/03/2022, 08:24:00"

I have not found any tutorials or forums that explain how to do this conversion in a C or C++ program developed with Visual Studio and I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Is sDateTime in ms?

Comment: What is `1643873040` ?

Comment: This page shows a summary of C [time management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/time-management?view=msvc-170) functions. Some convert epoch seconds to a fixed format string, or you can convert them to a `struct tm` and format that with `strftime()`, which works a bit like `sprintf()` does, but with its own format specifiers.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Clearly a [`time_t`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: What date is the value of 1 represent?  Is it 1 Jan 2000?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews [1 Jan 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 2):

Your value 1643873040 appears to be a [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) value.  It's unusual to have it as a string, because it's obviously an integer.  So the first thing to do is to convert it to an actual integer.  The traditional type in C for this sort of thing is `time_t`.  (It used to be 32 bits, but these days it's usually 64 bits.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

const char *sDateTime = "1643873040";
time_t t = strtoll(sDateTime, NULL, 10);
```

Next, to convert that number `t` into a human-readable format, the first step is to use the function [`localtime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime), which returns a pointer to a "broken down" time structure, `struct tm`:

```
struct tm *tmp = localtime(&t);
```

Next, you can use the [`strftime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) function to create a string from the `struct tm`:

```
char strbuf[30];
strftime(strbuf, sizeof(strbuf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tmp);
printf("%s\n", strbuf);
```

This prints:

```
2022-02-03 02:24:00
```

Or, you can print the fields from the `struct tm` directly:

```
printf("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
    tmp->tm_year+1900, tmp->tm_mon+1, tmp->tm_mday,
    tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec);
```

Here, though, you have to be careful, because the `tm_mon` field is 0-based, and `tmp_year` is offset by 1900.

These are the ways I always do it, although it must be admitted that the `localtime` function is problematic by modern standards, in that it returns a pointer to static data and is not therefore thread-safe.  There's a thread-safe or "reentrant" version you can use instead:

```
struct tm tmbuf;
tmp = localtime_r(&t, &tmbuf);
```

(Or, as you've learned, there's a different alternative version, `localtime_s`, although I'm not aware of any advantage it might have over `localtime_r`.)

Finally, for completeness I might mention that there's also a simpler way, that goes straight from the `time_t` value to a string, without any `localtime` calls or a `struct tm` at all:

```
printf("%s", ctime(&t));
```

This prints

```
Thu Feb  3 02:24:00 2022
```

but it's quite a bit less flexible, because there's no way to change it. `ctime`'s output format is fixed.

A `time_t` value like 1643873040 usually represents [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), also known as GMT.  The `localtime` function takes care of converting it to your local time zone (including [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) corrections, if necessary).  If you want UTC time instead, without applying time zone and DST corrections, you can call [`gmtime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime) instead of `localtime`.

This answer has been for C.  The `localtime`, `gmtime`, and `strftime` functions will work fine in C++ also, although C++ has its own, perhaps preferred ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) it should help you in dealing with time.
Also give a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419684/convert-epoch-milliseconds-to-utc-date-and-time-using-c) stack overflow question and answers

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the previous example, obtained based on your answers, so that now it works in VisualStudio:

```
    uint64_t timeStamp = 0;

    std::istringstream iss("1550267535");
    iss >> timeStamp;
        
    time_t localTime = timeStamp;

    struct tm timeInfo;
    localtime_s(&timeInfo, &localTime);

    printf ("%d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
        1900 + timeInfo.tm_year, timeInfo.tm_mon, timeInfo.tm_mday,
        timeInfo.tm_hour, timeInfo.tm_min, timeInfo.tm_sec);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've got a little buglet here, though, and it's unfortunately a classic one: your month is going to be off by one, because `tm_mon` is 0-based.