# How to generate current datetime with system's regional format in C++?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I'm looking for a way to get the current system date time formatted in a manner consistent with the system's region.

For example, a system in the US would have something like:
01-31-2022 1:59:00 PM

And a system in Europe would have something like:
31-01-2022 13:59:00

I've experimented a bit with using Boost but can't seem to get exactly what I'm specifying here; is there any library or implementation that might let me achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you provide the program which regional format you are using? Or Are you seeking to C++ program detect its time region and automatically format the date/time itself?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223096/outputting-date-and-time-in-c-using-stdchrono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we configure the locale for the user's default by imbuing the output stream with the empty-name locale (`locale("")`). Then we use the locale-dependent date and time formats with [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time). For example: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae2b2c620bd45243)

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::time_t raw_now = time(nullptr);

    std::tm now = *localtime(&raw_now);

    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout << std::put_time(&now, "My locale: %x %X\n");

    // For comparison, how we'd expect it to show up for a 
    // user configured for Great Britain:
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_GB.UTF-8"));
    std::cout << std::put_time(&now, "Great Britain: %x %X\n");
}
```

On my box (configured for the US), this produces the following output:

```
My locale: 02/16/2022 06:05:48 PM
Great Britain: 16/02/22 18:05:48
```

There is also a `%c` format to produce date and time, but this (at least normally) includes the day of the week (e.g., `Wed 16 Feb 2022 18:11:53 PST`) which doesn't fit with what you seem to want.

As a side-note: all compilers are supposed to accept at least `"C"` and `""` for locale names. Any other name (like the `en_GB.UTF-8` I've used above) depends on the compiler. You may need a different string if you're using a different compiler (I was testing with g++ on Linux).

Comment: Jerry! Not everyday our paths cross. I guess it was mainly because the question was capriciously tagged [tag:boost]. I'm glad you answered it, because I sure didn't  feel qualified here :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to query for `timezone`, and then use a format specifier when you output the timestamp. See the comment for `%c` in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html, and also https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html. As for linking, it's part of `libc` so adding `-lc` to your compiler invocation should be sufficient